# How to set a colour variable in JS

Tags: actionscript-3

I have these lines of code but I am afraid I couldn't define the variable. I tried with label but couldn't find the documentation.
Is for tables in Indesign app.

The script does not identify the "Red".

```
app.documents[0].stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().cells.everyItem().properties =
app.documents[0].stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().cells.everyItem().properties =
{
topEdgeStrokeColor : Red,
bottomEdgeStrokeColor : Red,
leftEdgeStrokeColor : Red,
rightEdgeStrokeColor : Red
}
```

I tried to define the variable for set the colour.

Comment: `'red'` or `'#ff0000'` should work.  Those are strings.

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to ask: have you already asked this over on the [official indesign forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/ct-p/ct-indesign)? (Especially since this isn't "JavaScript", it's Adobe's personal flavour of actionscript 3, based on an over-20-years-old variant of JS, with Adobe's APis on top)

Comment: Mike, thanks. I sent a thread but «community experts» never replied. There is a solution by menu by I need code.